# Structured Streaming + Kafka：Cannot send after the producer is closed

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

The structure streaming of the Sparks writes data to Kafka, throwing an exception:

> Cannot send after the producer is closed.

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("stream source 30361")
  .getOrCreate()

val eventSource_HS_OPT_EWB = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS)
  .option("subscribe", TOPIC_HS_OPT_EWB)
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 10000)
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .option("failOnDataLoss", false) //[2018-07-13]
  .load()
  .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema_HS_OPT_EWB).alias("parsed_value"))
  .selectExpr("parsed_value.*")

eventSource_HS_OPT_EWB.createOrReplaceTempView("hsOptEwb_tl")

val exp_bol: DataFrame = spark.sql("select * from hsOptEwb_tl")

var query_exp_bol: StreamingQuery = exp_bol.selectExpr("to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("kafka") // can be "orc", "json", "csv",memory,console etc.
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS)
  .option("topic", TOPIC_EVENT_WAYBILL)
  .option("checkpointLocation", CHECKPOINT_PATH_HS_OPT_EWB)
  .option("kafka.timeout.ms", 120000)
  .option("kafka.request.timeout.ms", 120000)
  .option("kafka.session.timeout.ms", 180000)
  .option("kafka.heartbeat.interval.ms", 60000)
  .option("kafka.retries", 10)
  .option("kafka.max.request.size", 10485760) //134217728//209715200
  .option("kafka.buffer.memory", 10485760)
  .start()
spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

kafka:0.10.1
spark:2.2
topic:10 partitions

Comment: Can you show the rest of the exception and code? For example, where is the `awaitForTermination` method?

Comment: ok，already added

Comment: I would guess that since your input stream is not continuous, there is no reason to use `writeStream` here as compared to a normal `mapPartitions` iterator function, and so the internal Kafka producer is closing itself because you're not sending any new data. Other than that, I'm not sure I see the need for Spark here when it's just a JDBC call to a database plus a multi-threaded Kafka producer, which is what Kafka Connect already gives you with the JDBC connector

Comment: it is continuous

Comment: A SQL query or dataframe is not continuous. I'm not sure what you mean... In fact, you're doing a `SELECT *` over a temp view, which doesn't do anything, so why aren't you using `eventSource_HS_OPT_EWB.writeStream`?